# Alias Defaults to Auto-generate

Tags: path-aliases

Afternoon Everyone,

I am having a few problems with a site we are having developed; although it is nothing significant it is quite annoying.

At the moment I am editing a fair amount of content ready for site-live but when I go to edit a page that I have names the node with a custom alias (ie /events/event1 ) I have to remember to go back into the node alias, uncheck the Automatic Alias box and put in the custom alias again.

If I don't do this, it becomes a second level page (ie /full-title-of-event-1 ) which obviously is not great.

Comment: Do you have Pathauto module installed? Do you have access to the Pathauto config page?

Comment: I am afraid I do not know as I currently do not have access to the modules page.

Comment: Then ask your site admin to set it up. It's something most admins should be able to easily install and configure. Bear in mind that Pathauto aliases can be regenerated in bulk, so it's probably best to leave as-is (don't override defaults) and then just do a bulk update later with a pattern specified per content-type (your site admin can do this all with minimal effort).

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your advice, I will head back to the developer as they hold the keys to some of the bits still.